# Returning more than one item

Tags: c#, function, boolean

How can I make a bool function return something alongside the bool? An example would be:

```
public bool MyBool(List<Item> a, string lookfor)
{

  foreach(Item it in a)
  {

    if(it.itemname == look for)
    {
      //Also return the item that was found!
      return true;
    }

  }
  return false;

}
```

So basically if something is true, I would also like to return that item alongside the bool. Is that possible?

Comment: As an example [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb347013(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I would always favor a lightweight class, or struct, that provides storage for the values you wish to return.  That way, you still return a single object, but get as much content as you like.  `out` works, but it can make messy methods.

Comment: If you can, create a class that holds the data and gives it semantic meaning. `Tuple`'s etc are good, but if you can make it *dead clear* to an outsider about what it is returning, then that is better again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, two options.

The first, return a result using `out` parameter modifier ([more info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx))

```
public bool MyBool(List<Item> a, string lookfor, out Item result)
```

or the second, return a result packed into [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public Tuple<bool, Item> MyBool(List<Item> a, string lookfor)
```

Comment: Three options: create a class containing your bool and the Item.

Comment: Note that tuple doesn't exist in .NET 3.5.

Comment: @JonB Yeah, but it's obvious I guess.

Comment: @JonB: I would say that in practice that's not really a third option. "Returning a class containing both items" is really a second option covering your use and the tuple one (given that is just a class containing two items).

Comment: @DonBoitnott I know, OP does not specify a target framework version so I use automatically the last one.

Answer (score 2):

You need an out parameter passed in the call, out parameters are expected to be set by the called method. So, for example, you could have something like this

```
public bool MyBool(List<Item> a, string lookfor, out Item found)
{
    found = a.SingleOrDefault(it => it.itemname == lookfor);
    return found != null;
}
```

in the calling code you could write

```
Item it;
if(ClassInstanceWithMethod.MyBool(ListOfItems, "itemToSearchFor", out it))
    Console.WriteLine(it.itemname);
```

However, I recommend to change the name of this method to something more obvious
(TryGetValue seems to be a perfect fit)

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [out keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) on a parameter. Here is a real world example from `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`

```
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    int index = this.FindEntry(key);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        value = this.entries[index].value;
        return true;
    }
    value = default(TValue);
    return false;
}
```